# "DEALER.DAT"148 Wrong open mode or access mode for write

Tags: cobol

I have no errors and I am using visual studios to compile. I have two input files  and two output files which are supposed to use transactions to update data in the dealer file onto the dealer-out file

```
   program-id. FREDERICKBOWSERProgram3 as "CSDP 241 .Program3".

   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.

   INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
   FILE-CONTROL.
       SELECT Dealer ASSIGN TO "Dealer.dat" ORGANIZATION IS SEQUENTIAL.

      SELECT Trans  ASSIGN TO "Trans.dat" ORGANIZATION IS SEQUENTIAL.                                
       SELECT DealOut ASSIGN TO "Dealer-Out.TXT"
               FILE STATUS IS DealOut-FILE-STATUS.
       SELECT RejectOut ASSIGN TO "Reject.TXT"
               FILE STATUS IS RejectOut-FILE-STATUS.
   data division.
   FILE SECTION.
   FD Dealer.
       01 INPUT1                      PIC X(165).

   FD Trans.
       01 INPUT2                      PIC X(32).
    FD DealOut.
           01 OUTPUT1                   PIC X(165).
    FD RejectOut.
           01 OUTPUT2                  PIC X(32).
   working-storage section.        
   01  SWITCHES.
       05  FIRST-EXECUTION-SWITCH        PIC X    VALUE "Y".
           88  FIRST-EXECUTION                        VALUE "Y".
       05  ALL-RECORDS-PROCESSED-SWITCH      PIC X    VALUE "N".
           88  ALL-RECORDS-PROCESSED                  VALUE "Y".
   01 PRINT-AREA.
    03  Dealer-Number                    Pic X(8).
           03  Dealer-Name.
               05  Last-Name                    Pic X(25).
               05  First-Name                   Pic X(15).
               05  Middle-Name                  Pic X(10).
           03  Address-Line-1                   Pic X(38).
           03  City                             Pic X(21).
           03  State-Or-Country                 Pic X(5).
           03  Postal-Code                      Pic 9(5).
           03  Consignment-Percent              Pic 9(3).
           03  Last-Sold-Amount                 Pic S9(7)v99.
           03  Last-Sold-Date                   Pic 9(8).
           03  Sold-To-Date                     Pic S9(7)v99.
           03  Commission-To-Date               Pic S9(7)v99. 
   01 PRINT-AREA2.
       03  Transaction-Date                 Pic  9(8).
       03  Transaction-Text.
           05  Transaction-Type             Pic  X(4).
           05  Transaction-Dealer-Number    Pic  X(8).
       03  Transaction-Price                Pic  S9(7)v99.
       03  Transaction-Qty                  Pic  9(3).   
   01  FILE-STATUS-FIELDS.
       05  DealOut-FILE-STATUS     PIC XX.
           88  DealOut-SUCCESSFUL           VALUE "00".
       05  RejectOut-FILE-STATUS     PIC XX.
           88  RejectOut-SUCCESSFUL           VALUE "00".
   01 NEWNEW.
       05 CURRT-TRANS                  PIC S9(7)v99.
       05 CURRT-COMM                   PIC  9(3)v99.
   procedure division.

   000-UPDATE-TRANS-MASTER.
    OPEN INPUT Trans
               EXTEND Dealer
        OUTPUT DealOut     
         RejectOut.

       MOVE LOW-VALUE TO Dealer-Number.     
       PERFORM 200-PROCESS-TRANS
           UNTIL ALL-RECORDS-PROCESSED.

       CLOSE  Dealer
              Trans
              DealOut
              RejectOut.
       STOP RUN.
   200-PROCESS-TRANS.
       PERFORM 210-READ-TRANS.
       PERFORM 220-PROCESS-DEALER
               UNTIL Dealer-Number >= Transaction-Dealer-Number.
       IF     Dealer-Number = HIGH-VALUE
               AND Transaction-Dealer-Number = HIGH-VALUE
               SET ALL-RECORDS-PROCESSED TO TRUE
       ELSE
           IF INPUT1 = Transaction-Dealer-Number
               PERFORM 250-APPLY-TRANSACTION
           ELSE
               PERFORM 260-WRITE-ERROR-TRANSACTION.

   210-READ-TRANS.
       READ Trans INTO PRINT-AREA2
           AT END
               MOVE HIGH-VALUE TO Transaction-Dealer-Number.


   220-PROCESS-DEALER.

       IF FIRST-EXECUTION
           PERFORM 230-READ-OLD-DEALER
           MOVE "N" TO FIRST-EXECUTION-SWITCH
      ELSE
           PERFORM 240-WRITE-NEW-DEALER.
           PERFORM 230-READ-OLD-DEALER.
   230-READ-OLD-DEALER.

      READ Dealer INTO PRINT-AREA
           AT END
               MOVE HIGH-VALUE TO Dealer-Number.
   240-WRITE-NEW-DEALER.

       WRITE INPUT1 FROM PRINT-AREA.
       IF NOT DealOut-SUCCESSFUL
           DISPLAY "WRITE ERROR ON NEWMAST FOR ITEM NUMBER "
           Dealer-Number
            DISPLAY "FILE STATUS CODE IS " DealOut-FILE-STATUS
            SET ALL-RECORDS-PROCESSED TO TRUE.

   250-APPLY-TRANSACTION.
      MULTIPLY Transaction-Qty BY Transaction-Price GIVING CURRT-TRANS.
      ADD CURRT-TRANS TO Sold-To-Date.
      MULTIPLY CURRT-TRANS BY Consignment-Percent GIVING CURRT-COMM.
      ADD CURRT-COMM TO Commission-To-Date.



   260-WRITE-ERROR-TRANSACTION.

        WRITE OUTPUT2 FROM PRINT-AREA2.
        IF NOT RejectOut-SUCCESSFUL
           DISPLAY "WRITE ERROR ON ERRTRAN FOR ITEM NUMBER "
               Transaction-Dealer-Number
           DISPLAY "FILE STATUS CODE IS " RejectOut-FILE-STATUS
           SET ALL-RECORDS-PROCESSED TO TRUE.


   end program FREDERICKBOWSERProgram3.
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `OPEN EXTEND` for Dealer.

The use of this is to add records to the "end" of a file. The records prior to that remain where they were, unchanged.

`EXTEND` is like `OUTPUT`, except it retains existing data in place, and allows your program to add to it.

With EXTEND, you'd not expect to `READ` the file. And you'd not expect to update records.

You need to open the file `I-O`.

You should use the `FILE STATUS` for all your files, and check the value after each IO is complete.

You are not using "scope-delimiters". That would be OK prior to 1985, when they were introduced, but for new code these days you should use scope-delimiters.

A good example of why is this, from your code:

```
   220-PROCESS-DEALER.

       IF FIRST-EXECUTION
           PERFORM 230-READ-OLD-DEALER
           MOVE "N" TO FIRST-EXECUTION-SWITCH
      ELSE
           PERFORM 240-WRITE-NEW-DEALER.
           PERFORM 230-READ-OLD-DEALER.
```

Look at the penultimate line. It ends with a full-stop period, which terminates the scope of the IF. The following line, which is indented as though it should be part of the IF, is not part of the IF, it is unconditional.

That mistake is much less easy to make when you code like this:

```
   220-PROCESS-DEALER.

       IF FIRST-EXECUTION
           PERFORM 230-READ-OLD-DEALER
           MOVE "N" TO FIRST-EXECUTION-SWITCH
       ELSE
           PERFORM 240-WRITE-NEW-DEALER
           PERFORM 230-READ-OLD-DEALER
       END-IF
       .
```

Note that I've made the full-stop/period which terminates the paragraph as easy to spot as possible, and not attached it to any line of code. You can now copy/paste that code without worrying whether it should retain the full-stop/period or not, because no line of code has one.

Answer (score 0):

After writing `Procedure Division`, when you are closing all the working-spaces, make sure you have used `goback.` keyword

for ex:

```
CLOSE  Dealer
       Trans
       DealOut
       RejectOut.

       goback.
```